# How to run a multiple membership hierarchical model in Stata?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, multiple-membership

I have a dataset of educators and the courses that they designed. My original thought was to do a multilevel model where courses are nested within educators, and the outcome is whether the course ever was offered publicly to students. I was fitting this model using `melogit` in Stata.

However, I realized that courses could have been designed by multiple teachers. So courses could potentially be nested within multiple teachers (or vice versa). Does anyone know how to fit this type of "multiple membership" model in Stata?

Comment: This does have statistical content which stops it being off-topic as a question on how to do something in Stata.